# webdav-server and webdav-fs 404 not found

Tags: node.js, ms-word, webdav

I am starting with the webdav server, I am looking to use webdav-server and webdav-fs together, of course having a visual interface on a website behind, I want to open and modify word files (ms-word).
I'm localhost at the moment.
I have a webdav-server which works but returns me a 404.
When I use the url directly from the browser, webdav-server reacts to the request for the file but only returns a 404.

Webdav-fs also retrieves the 404 request and never the file.
I'm running out of ideas to move forward and resolve the problem.

Hoping for help with this complex topic.

Package :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdav-server
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdav-fs